# Combining same-sized arrays without loop?

Tags: arrays, performance, vba

In my VBA project, I have two arrays of strings, ArrA & ArrB. They are identically sized. I would like to change ArrA such that if A = B if B is populated, and unchanged otherwise. In other words:

`If ArrB(i) <> "" Then ArrA(i) = ArrB(i)`

I could obviously just loop through `i = 0 to UBound(ArrA)`, but am looking to avoid a loop for performance reasons. Is there any other, better, way to accomplish this?

Comment: Array of what? PLease, be more specific...

Comment: Strings. Edited question.

Comment: How will you determine that `ArrB` is populated?  Assuming you have a trick for that, you can always just set one equal to the other and it will update the reference: `ArrA = ArrB` is valid.  You are left with **1** array and two variables referring to it.

Comment: Sorry -- my bad. must be quittin' time... should be `If ArrB(i) <> ""`